# Android: openFileOutput only works in the MainActivity but not within any other Activity

Tags: java, android, file, android-studio

as the title states, the following Code, does have Three Files:

In **MainActivity.java** openFileOutput works very well

```
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
   super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
   setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
   startActivity(new Intent(MainActivity.this, Pop.class));

   //openFileOutput works fine
   FileOutputStream xml = openFileOutput(checklistname, MODE_PRIVATE);
   }
```

**dataBasis.java** to create a File each time it is called.

```
public class dataBasis extends Activity {
    private String date ="";
    dataBasis() throws FileNotFoundException {
        FileOutputStream xml = openFileOutput("dataBasis.xml", MODE_PRIVATE);
    }
}
```

In the **Pop.java** by creating an instance of dataBasis, a File "dataBasis.xml" will be created.

```
public void onSelectChecklist(View v) throws FileNotFoundException{
    dataBasis da = new dataBasis();
}
```

Here is where the Error does occur which looks as the following:

[image: Error]

Comment: You have a bug in `Pop.java`. My guess is that you have tried creating an instance of `MainActivity` manually, which will not work. However, since your [mcve] does not show `Pop.java`, we cannot really help with that. If you could update your [mcve] to include the stack trace *as text*, and include your `Pop` class, perhaps we can provide more specific recommendations.

Comment: It's a `NullPointerException` for MainActivity which means you're using something of MainActivity which is not initalized.

Comment: Post more of your code please, According to the error you must look at mainactiviy.java line 53, The onclick gets a NULLOBJECTREFERENCE so what ever you are calling doesnt exist,, jsut check those few things

Comment: I reedited the post, check it out!

Answer (score 0):

Hmm, it seems that you need a reference to your Context to call the `openFileOutput()` method on. You can use the `getApplicationContext()` method to do this like so:

```
public class dataBasis extends Activity {
    private String date ="";
    dataBasis() throws FileNotFoundException {
        FileOutputStream xml = getApplicationContext().openFileOutput("dataBasis.xml", MODE_PRIVATE);
    }
}
```

Depending on what you want you might need to use a different method to get the [Context](https://blog.mindorks.com/understanding-context-in-android-application-330913e32514).

Comment: Sadly didn't work out. Seemingly calling the openFileOutput function of another class doesn't work.